# Optimization Routine in Fortran 90

Tags: fortran, mathematical-optimization, fortran90, gfortran

I am doing (trying to do) numerical optimization in Fortran 90, on a Windows 7 machine with the gfortran compiler. I have a function, pre-written by someone else, which returns the loglikelihood of a function, given a large set of parameters (about 60 parameters in total) passed in. I am trying to replicate someone's results, so I know the final parameter values, but I was to try and re-estimate them and, eventually, extend their model and use different data. I've been trying the uobyqa.f90 routine available [here](http://jblevins.org/mirror/amiller/uobyqa.f90), which has not been particularly successful thus far.

My questions are: First, for an optimization problem with a large number of parameters (over 60), can anyone suggest the best freely available routine? Derivatives are not available, and would be costly to estimate numerically, hence trying the uobyqa routine first. Also, would implementing parallelization aid significantly in solving this problem? And, if so, could anyone suggest an optimization routine that already implements parallelization using openmp?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a good suggestion for a specific optimization strategy, but the [NLopt](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt) package has a few derivative-free optimizers that can handle larger numbers of variables. Worth checking out. I've found the Fortran interface to be very easy to use.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I've tried the NLopt package, though still with limited success. Doesn anyone have experience with Genetic algorithms and fortran? I've been experimenting with pikai, parly because there's a parallellized version. How do these algorithms perform with large numbers of parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Do a regular (published academic) literature search on this question first.
Maybe try including "LAPACK" with your other search terms (e.g. "optimization", "uobyqa", etc) to see relavant work by other parties.